# Finding a substring from input

Tags: c++, if-statement, input, substring, substr

For my project, one of the options for an input is "I n" where n is a number. I am trying to get that input in an if statement for "I" from a substring, and then getting the number to eventually use stringstream to turn it into an integer.

Here is my test code right now:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    cout << "Type in \"I 2\": " << endl;
    string in = "";
    string numstr = "";

    while(in != "Q" && in != "q")
    {
        cin >> in;

        //Input cases
        if(in.substr(0,1) == "I")
        {
            numstr = in.substr(1,1); //numstr is the number in string form
            cout << in << "+" << numstr << endl; //I want it to output "I+2"
                                                //but it outputs "I+"
        }
        else
        {

            cout << "That was not an option. Try again." << endl;
        }

    }
    return 0;
}
```

Right now the output is:

```
I+
That was not an option. Try again.
```

What can I change to get it to recognize "2"? When I change the substring to (2,1) I get an out_of_range exception

Comment: `cin >> in` reads up to the first whitespace character. So, it just reads `'I'`. The number is still sitting in the input stream, waiting to be read.

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH. I have been trying to figure out this program for like 8 hours now, this is one of the last things that is bugging me

Answer (score 0):

Couple of comments and since I haven't programmed in a while, this may be incorrect, but recommendations for instead of using != for string comparison, I think it might be better if you use !in.equalsIgnorecase("Q"), then for your if statement in.startsWith("I") then instead of 1,1, I'd think it should be 1,2 (or maybe 2,3?), but your thing says 2,1, which wouldn't make sense. Hope that helps. Below is how I'd set it up!

```
while(!in.equalsIgnoreCase"q")
{
        cin >> in;

        //Input cases
        if(in.startsWith("I")
        {`enter code here`
            numstr = in.substring(1,2); //maybe in.substring(2,3), if original doesn't work
            cout << in << "+" << numstr << endl; //I want it to output "I+2"
        }
}
```

Comment: Igor Tandetnik found my issue, it was that cin >> in only reads until the first whitespace character. The 2nd argument of substring is how far it goes, not where it stops. So 2,1 means it starts at character 2, and goes 1 character. I think it is like that in Java though. Thank you though!